# add view from MainActivity to another xml file layout

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I'd like to add an ImageView from my MainActivity to another xml file (layout.xml) pragmatically, i'v tried this code but it doesn't work, here's the code source of Mainactivity, activity_main.xml and layout.xml:

Mainactivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
LinearLayout linearLayout;
ImageView imageView;
Dialog dialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = new ImageView(this);
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.id_layout);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
    linearLayout.addView(imageView);

    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(linearLayout);
    dialog.show();

}}
```

here's the xml file for main activity 
Activity_main.xml:

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="sofware.dz.test.MainActivity">


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

here's the code source of the xml file 
layout.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/id_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you don't want to actually want to programmatically edit any XML, but rather add an ImageView to an inflated layout that is defined using XML. Is the `layout.xml` layout inflated anywhere? In the code you currently have written, you're attempting to find the root view of `layout.xml` inside of `activity_main.xml`. You can't add anything to that layout until it exists somewhere as a view. Perhaps you're trying to create a `Dialog` that has `layout.xml` as the root view, then add an `ImageView` to that?

Comment: Yes that's what  i'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're inflating your `layout.xml` anywhere.

You can replace the line

```
linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.id_layout);
```

with this:

```
linearLayout = (LinearLayout)LayoutInflater.from((Context) this).inflate(R.layout.layout, null)
```

You can have the inflated view referenced as you linear layout as that's the root view of your xml. If you had something else as the root, you would then have to add the `findViewById(R.id.id_layout)` call at the end.

Comment: Thank's  that's what i'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to create a `Dialog` with the layout defined in `layout.xml` as the content view, then add an `ImageView` from your activity to that, try the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);

    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout); // this inflates layout.xml in the dialog

    LinearLayout layout = dialog.findViewById(R.id.id_layout); // grab root view from inflated layout
    layout.addView(imageView);

    dialog.show(); // show the dialog, which now contains the ImageView
}
```

How this works, step-by-step:

1. Set the content view of your activity, which you're already doing: 
   `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
2. Create the `ImageView` you want to add (you're also already doing this):
   `imageView = new ImageView(this); 
   imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);`
3. Create the dialog, and set its content view to the resource ID of your layout.xml layout (which inflates it):
   `dialog = new Dialog(this);
   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout); // this inflates layout.xml in the dialog`
4. Get the root view from the inflated layout within the Dialog:
   `LinearLayout layout = dialog.findViewById(R.id.id_layout); // grab root view
   layout.addView(imageView);`
5. Add your ImageView to the root view:
   `layout.addView(imageView);`

Comment: Your solution is correct  too,  that's what i'm looking for, Thank's